# Compute a reduced table with weighted averages

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, weighted-average

Scenario: A table with a list of purchases, with some items purchased multiple times, with potentially different quantities and prices.

[image: Input]

Desired Result: A table with one row per item and the weighted average of price.

[image: Desired result]

I know how to compute the Count column using SUMIF. But I don't know how to compute with weighted average - there's no AVERAGE.WEIGHTEDIF function. And I'm not sure how to reduce the number of rows, though I suspect I can use UNIQUE.

[Here's an example of the input and desired output](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o9UW_Z0pUpzXu73AMvPGszgG36dhSpBaPH-DnlL-n_k/edit?usp=sharing), where the output has been hand-crafted - I'm looking for a formulaic way to generate the output.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Mike

I've tried various combinations of UNIQUE and AVERAGE.WEIGHTED but haven't found a combination that does what I need.

Comment: just use your Total Cost, which you can get with SUMIFS and divide that by COUNT: `=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,F2)/SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,F2)`

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=byrow(unique(tocol(A2:A,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,sumif(A:A,Σ,B:B),average.weighted(filter(C:C,A:A=Σ),filter(B:B,A:A=Σ)),sumif(A:A,Σ,D:D)}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @rockinfreakshow. It works. And it's fascinating - I'm going to spend some time trying to understand what it does. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using QUERY and an array which generates the headers within the formula:

```
=arrayformula(query(query({A:B,B:B*C:C},
"select Col1,sum(Col2),sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null group by Col1",1),
"select Col1,Col2,Col3/Col2,Col3 label Col2 'Count', Col3/Col2 'Weight Average Unit Cost', Col3 'Total Cost'",1))
```

N.B. the 'Total Cost' column in the source table is redundant in this approach so is ignored - it is generated within the QUERY.